# Preg capture the first apostrophe

Tags: mysql, regex, pcre

I've mysql function from lib like this `PREG_CAPTURE('/id\=\'(.*)\'/i', xml, 1, 1)` , and I trying capture element from this log

```
"xml":id='t6e8u-73' type='chat'><body>\uD83D\uDE31</body><thread>fU9ie4T0mIaz</thread><active xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/><request xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/></message>"
```

The result is a captured all of them, but i need capture only first element like this `id=t6e8u-73` Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using lazy quantifier:

```
id\=\'(.*?)\'
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kbSY44/1)